# Launch a process with limited permissions

Tags: command-line, permissions, sandbox

I'd like to be able to launch processes with very limited permissions from the command line, basically so that I can run a process that I don't understand without it having access to things in my user area. For example, if I get a package from some colleague who has a tendency to write overly intrusive installers, I could do something like this:

```
> subdo make
```

would run `make` in such that it wouldn't be allowed to touch any parent directories. Does any such functionality exist in Unix?

Comment: You are looking for chroot, also called "BSD-jails".

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use the `nobody` account:

```
sudo -u nobody make
```

`nobody` should never have permission to write to anything other than world writable files.

Answer (score 1):

> would run make in such that it wouldn't be allowed to touch any parent directories.

This basically describes chroot:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_Root

Note that, however, when you chroot the process will not have access to anything except the folders under the new root. That means that e.g. if the process needs to run some programs from e.g. `/usr/bin` or e.g. load some shared libraries from `/usr/lib`, it won't be able to do that unless you actually copy these under the new root. It really depends on the program you are trying to run.

You can find a lot of tutorials for different programs, e.g. here's a sample BIND chroot tutorial:

- http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Chroot-BIND8-HOWTO-2.html

Comment: Note that chroot is only useful against cooperative programs. A malicious program can easily escape the chroot unless you take a lot of extra precautions. For starters, there must be no process that the chrooted process can `ptrace` (so no process running as the same user outside the chroot, or non-parent `ptrace` disabled). Other bad things the chrooted process can do include network access (disable it for that user with `iptables -m owner --uid-owner …`), fork bombs (set stringent limits), etc.

Comment: Agree, thanks for the additional info Gilles!

Answer (score 0):

[en.wikipedia.org: Systrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systrace)

[OpenBsd man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=systrace&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&arch=i386&format=html)

Generate policy:

```
systrace -A -d /etc/systrace/make.policy/ \
         -E /var/log/systrace_make.log make
```

Edit policy with your favorite text editor:

```
vi /etc/systrace/make.policy/
```

Thereafter, launch process with restrictions:

```
systrace -a -d /etc/systrace/make.policy/ \
         -E /var/log/systrace_make.log make
```

Look at my another one [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81808/are-there-additional-ways-to-protect-ssh-connections-besides-firewall-and-rsa-ke/)  about using systrace with sshd

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I will explain now how to use systrace, better. But anyway, wikipedia links, while openbsd and linux keep using systrace, should not be changed.